# pgfplots, table-plot: Could not parse input as a floating point number

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I get `Could not parse input 'A' as a floating point number`

What do I have to change here?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
]
\addplot[] table[y index=1] {
name data     color    
A       22        gray     
C       5          blue     
D       5         orange     
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addplot[] table[y index=1,x expr=\coordindex] { ... `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
]
\addplot[] table[y index=1,x expr=\coordindex] {
name data     color    
A       22        gray     
C       5          blue     
D       5         orange     
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D},xtick=data]
\addplot[] table[y index=1] {
name data     color    
A       22        gray     
C       5          blue     
D       5         orange     
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good! ____________________